# Adding leading characters to string in SQL

Tags: sql, string

I have a stored procedure.  I pass in 1 variable, called `@p_FR`, which is a char(6).  However, the passed value is not always 6 characters long.  Sometimes the value is only 4 or 5 characters long.  I need to make sure that the string is always 6 characters long.  For example, if `@p_FR` is 8534, then I need to add 2 leading 0's to `@p_FR`, so it would be 008534.

I tried doing

```
set @fr = right('000000', @p_FR, 6)
```

`@fr` is a varchar(6)

but when `@p_FR` is 8534, @fr is still 8534.  I need it to be 008534.

I also set the following block of code in a fresh query, and I still got 8534.

```
declare @p_FR as char(6),
    @fr as varchar(6)
set @p_FR = '8534'
set @fr = right('000000' + @p_FR, 6) 
select @fr
```

Comment: Any specific DBMS?  The string functions that might be used aren't necessarily the same for all

Comment: **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: Figured it out.  The @p_FR needed to be a varchar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use rtrim to remove blanks:

```
declare @p_FR as char(6),
    @fr as varchar(6)
set @p_FR = '8534'
set @fr = right('000000' + rtrim(@p_FR), 6) 
select @fr
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve the problem would be to use varchar(6) instead of char(6) by doing so you don't have to worry about trailing spaces since varchar only stores the string and doesn't include trailing spaces to fill up.

If that is not an option then you can use RTRIM(@p_FR) assuming your RDBMS supports RTRIM. You didn't specify what RDBMS you are using but I am assuming SQL Server of some sort.